# Google Cloud Storage Bucket is not associated with CNAME on DNS record for using my domain as origin

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I intend to use Google Cloud Storage through my own domain name supereye.co.uk .

However,

When I try to associate CNAME on my DNS record for supereye.co.uk with the Google Cloud Bucket production-supereye-co-uk, I get the following message when I try to access to

production-supereye-co-uk.supereye.co.uk/static/default-coverpng  :

```
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchBucket</Code>
<Message>The specified bucket does not exist.</Message>
</Error>
```

What shall I do ?

Important note : This is not a static site. This is a Django Application that runs on Google Cloud Engine and Django has its own URL routing mechanism. It means Django translates everything after supereye.co.uk/URL , I wonder how this should work.

Comment: So you have a django app at supereye.co.uk/.... but you want to point a cname record to supereye.co.uk?

Comment: Good question. I have a django app at supereye.co.uk , but I want to use Google Cloud Storage bucket that is associated with supereye.co.uk to be accessible through supereye.co.uk/data for instance, not through "c.storage.googleapis.com". How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you cannot simply just add a CNAME record to redirect some traffic to a give URL.
You are going to have to do one of the following to get your desired result:

- Serve traffic to a new sub domain data.supereye.co.uk which will host your content.
- Proxy data through your django app, this is not ideal but would allow you to easily protect your data with authentication or authorization.
- Proxy content through nginx, using nginx you proxy the request (forward) through to your cloud bucket. Light weight and fairly simple to implement.
- Use a gcp loadbalance to split the traffic, you can setup a LB to split requests between the backend group and the bucket using host/ path rules.

I would either got for the LB or the nginx proxy as these will be the easiest to implement (depending on your setup). If you want any form of access control go for proxying the request through your django app.